# How to Json Object Constructor with std::initializer_list and std::pair?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, std-pair, stdinitializerlist

I wanna create a constructor and thats create Json Object from passing.

```
class JsonObject {
    std::map<std::string, QVariant> mMapOfMarks;

public:
    JsonObject(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, QVariant> > marksMap) :
            mMapOfMarks(marksMap) {
    }
    void display() {
        for (auto entry : mMapOfMarks)
            con << QString::fromStdString(entry.first) << " : " << entry.second ;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

this is initializing object list

```
JsonObject json_obj
{
    { "Riti", 2 },
    { "Jack", "4asdf" } ,
    {"sdfsdf","sdfd"}
};
```

and display it well, output:

```
> "Jack"    :  QVariant(QString, "4asdf")  
> "Riti"    :  QVariant(int, 2)
> "sdfsdf"  :  QVariant(QString, "sdfd")
```

but i want to construct nested json object like below? How can i do that?

sample jsonobject that i want, key is string but value type changeble such as int, double , string, float, char or any known data type

```
JsonObject json_obj
{
    { "Riti", 2 },//int
    { "Jack", "4asdf" } ,//String
    {"sdfsdf", // object
        {"scvzx",342423.45} // double
    }
};
```

Comment: `{"sdfsdf",
        JsonObject{{"scvzx",342423.45}}
    }` ?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'JsonObject::JsonObject(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
         { "object", JsonObject{{"dsdf", 43534}} }

Comment: Well, that's to be expected, you don't have a constructor that accepts JsonObject objects, only a list of `std::pair<...>`.

Comment: `{"sdfsdf", QVariant::fromValue(JsonObject{{"scvzx",342423.45}}) }` ?